# CakePHP Tags Plugin Pagination Issue

Tags: cakephp, tags, cakedc

I am having issues getting CakeDC's tag's plugin to work. I have read the documentation very carefully, but it seems the docs are very old.

```
// Totally works. Does what it is supposed to do, does not 
// complain of missing models.
        $tag =  $this->Upload->Tagged->find('tagged', 
        array('by' => $tagname, 'model' => 'Upload', 'conditions' => 
        array( 'Upload.soft_delete !=' => 1) ));


// 100% correct according to the 3 year old documentation. 
// Complains of a missing  "taggeds" model.
// Table taggeds for model Tagged was not found in datasource default.
// Undefined index: tagged [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2731]


        $this->paginate['Tagged'] = array(
                        'model' => 'Upload',   
                        'tagged',
                        'by' => $tagname);

        $tag = $this->paginate('Tagged');
```

I read the documentation here at: https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/wiki/Find-tagged-objects

At first, I experienced the Indirect modification of overloaded property $paginate ... no effect" bug until I added  public $paginate = array(); to that the top of my controller. This has not helped the other error.

Hopefully I am missing something simple here.

UPDATE: I changed the code to look like this

```
$this->Paginator->settings['Tagged'] = array(
        'tagged',
        'model' => 'Upload',    
        'by' => $tagname
    ); 

$this->Paginator->paginate('Tagged');
```

and I get this error: Error: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Answer (score 3):

I eventually made it work adding in the top of Controller

```
public $components = array('Paginator');
```

Then in my method

```
$this->Paginator->settings['Tagged'] = array(
    'tagged',
    'model' => 'Upload',   
    'by' => $tagname
);
$this->Paginator->paginate('Tagged');
```

Answer (score 0):

> I experienced the Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   $paginate ... no effect" bug

That's your issue and not really a bug. CakePHP has changed a little, try this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings['Tagged'] = array(
    'tagged',
    'model' => 'Upload',   
    'by' => $tagname
);
$this->Paginator->paginate('Tagged');
```

You're welcome to improve the documentation. We're maintaining currently 14 plugins *for free*, any kind of help is appreciated. Give something back and help improving the docs. :)

Comment: "Error: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object" as well as " Indirect modification of overloaded property SearchesController::$Paginator has no effect"